# Npgsql custom type handler?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Anyone familiar with writing a custom type handler? I would like to map some enum's to integers in the database.  I'm using Npgsql 4.1.1 - I'm failing to find any good examples.

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2675

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this? I am struggling with the same issue.